# Calculating MSE, RMSE with a certain range of data frame rows until the end of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, mse

I have a data frame `df` which has two column `True` and `Prediction` while the data frame has 1000 rows. I want to calculate MSE and RMSE using function from sklearn  `mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)` . But I want to keep calculating them in a pattern such that, the 1st MSE will be calculated on the first 20 rows of `True` and `prediction` column values. Then next MSE will be on 21-40 row values from the `True` and `Prediction` column. Thus I want to calculate a bunch of MSE and RMSE taking every 20 rows consecutively from the total 1000 rows and arranging them in a data frame. I am not being able to find loop condition for that. I tried  `for i in range(0,len(df),20)` but its not working. How could I solve this?
For example, the data frame is

```
>df
    True  Prediction
0     5      5
1     6      4
2     7      2
3     2      3
..
1000  1      3
```

The output will be a data frame like this

```
   MSE   RMSE
0  1.5   2.5
1   1    0.5
2   1    1.2
...
50  2    3.7
```

As each MSE and RMSE will be based on 20 rows of True and Prediction value, there will be only 50 rows in the new data frame of MSE and RMSE

Comment: Could you edit your question to include example data and corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for MSE:

```
mse = df.groupby(lambda i: int(i / 20)).agg({'True': lambda x: list(x), 'Prediction': lambda x: list(x)})
mse = mse.apply(lambda r: mean_squared_error(r['True'], r['Prediction']), axis=1)
mse.head(5)
```

See live implementation [here](https://1000words-hq.com/n/RHO0cp0KU1m)